# Conda installing multiple packages instead of just one

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, conda

I am quiet new with python and coding itself. I use conda to manage my environments. I encountered that when I try to install packages with `conda install` conda tries to install more than the package I want. For instance, when installing numpy, conda wants to install 7 other packages... matplotlib even more. I looked it up online and I understood that I dont really need any other packages to use eg. numpy. Or am I wrong? Is it better to use pip install? I really want to avoid having a mess in my environment, since everything is new for me.

Comment: It's because the package you installing uses some other packages as dependencies so they also got installed along with that package in order for the package to work properly

Comment: Exactly, as @tax evader told you. It doesn't matter that extra packages have been installed, they take up almost no memory, they only serve for the proper functioning of numpy

Comment: The "real mess" starts when you have hundreds of packages in your env, so don't worry for now! =) With conda, the extra packages are installed to make them compatible with each other, that is a good thing! Moreover, sooner or later you are probably going to install them. In any case, if you want to learn how to deal with dependencies it is OK to install all packages one by one with pip... or with  "conda install --no-deps name_package".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I get it now! Understood wrongly before C:

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know the package dependency

1. pip https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/
2. conda https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

when you install a package, the dependency package will be installed too.